# Как реализовать border?

Tags: javascript, css

Фиксированный `header` на всех страницах. В `ul` есть 4 `li` (имена страниц), и на текущей странице у соответствующего `li` должен появляться `border-bottom`. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Ах да: `border-bottom` у `li` должен соответствующе меняться при смене страницы.

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>some text 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="active">some text 2</a></li>
  <li><a>some text 3</a></li>
  <li><a>some text 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Добавил дополнительное описание вопроса.